# The IDPAGE argument passed to the getPage function is not of type numeric Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to add a new page called result.cfml to the ColdFusion website. This page(result.cfml)  contains all basic Html tags and displays inside main.cfml. I see other page( result2.cfml) has the same setup, and it works fine inside main.cfml. However, I am not be able to view the page(result.cfml). So do i have to register this result.cfml within main.cfml?
Here is an error that i got when calling the result.cfml. Please help me.

**The IDPAGE argument passed to the getPage function is not of type numeric.
If the component name is specified as a type of this argument, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible.**

main.cfml

```
<div><img src="/images/titles/<cfoutput>#session.language#</cfoutput>/stepfinal.png" usemap="#STEPS"  /></div>
$box:final$
```

final.cfml

```
 <form action="<cfoutput>#application.site.index#</cfoutput>" method="post">                            
    <input name="event" type="hidden" value="update-final" />
    <input name="tpPayment" type="hidden" value="A" />              
    <button type="submit" style="height:30"></button>
</form>
<form action="<cfoutput>#application.site.index#</cfoutput>" method="post">                         
    <input name="event" type="hidden" value="update-final" />
    <input name="tpPayment" type="hidden" value="B" />              
    <button type="submit" style="height:30"></button>
</form>
```

update-final.cfml

```
<cfif form.tpPayment is "B">
     <cflocation addtoken="no" url="#application.site.index#/page/result"/> 
</cfif>
<cfif form.tpPayment is "A">
   <cflocation addtoken="no" url="#application.site.index#/page/result2"/> 
</cfif>
```

result.cfml

```
<h1>Title1</h1>
<p>some other paragraphs here</p>
```

result2.cfml

```
<h1>Title2</h1>
<p>some other paragraphs here</p>
```

getPage() function

```
    <cffunction name="getPage" access="public" returntype="query" output="no">
<cfargument name="idPage" type="numeric" required="no">
<cfquery name="qryPage" datasource="#application.global.dsn#">
Select idPage
     , idTemplate
     , idSection
     , nmPage
     , nmFile
     , tpFile
     , dsTitle
     , dsTitleContent
     , stPage
     , flMenu
     , nmMenu
     , flSiteMap
     , dsContentTitle
     , dsPage
     , dtSchedule
     , dtExpire
     , flProtected
     , cdGrantedKeys
     , dtCreate
     , dtLastUpdate
  From Page
 <cfif IsDefined("arguments.idPage")>
 Where idPage = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#arguments.idPage#">
 </cfif>
 Order by nmPage
</cfquery>
<cfreturn qryPage>
```

Comment: Sounds like there is some kind of framework in use (probably a home grown one rather than a community supported one). We would need a lot more information to be able to help you.

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: What type of architecture is being used? How does reault.cfml display 'inside main.cfml'? What is different in result2.cfml? Share the code form main.cfml that would 'display' result.cfml.

Comment: I just add more codes above. Please take  a look.

Comment: Where is the `getPage()` function? I do not see it in the code above. That said, the error message seems pretty self explanatory. The function expects a number, but was passed a string (or something else) instead.

Comment: Nothing you provided really helps. The code from main.cfml shows nothing on how result.cfml is displayed. Does the application use Application.cfm or Application.cfc? If so, include any code that may be relevant to how pages are displayed.

Comment: And, as Leigh pointed out, post the code that is actually using the `getPage()` method.

Comment: I have to say that I don't know where the getPage() is?

Comment: Then I am not sure we can help you. The error message should tell you the page and line number, if not, you will need to turn on robust exception handling in the ColdFusion Administrator

Comment: I found it. Please take a look

Comment: As Leigh pointed out, the error message states the problem. `getPage()` expects a number, but is being passed a value that is not a number. You need to find where `getPage()` is called and try to figure out why the value being passed is not numeric.

Comment: Do i have to add this new page to database? it seems like getPage() queries the datasource and checks for pageID.

Comment: Without knowing how your application works, we cannot say, with any certainty that it does need to be added to the DB. The error is saying that `getPage()` is being passed a value that is not numeric. Even if you add the page to the DB, that will not solve the error as it is being reported.

Comment: @user1874435 - That is an application specific rule. Since only *you* know the rules, we really have no way of answering that correctly. Based on the limited information posted, we can only tell you that it is a validation error. It error occurs when you invoke getPage(someValue). The function expects a number, but that is not what you are passing in. Hence the error. You need to figure out *why* the code is not passing the correct type of value. BTW - That query is never executed, so that is not the cause of this specific error.

Comment: Ok, Thank you all guys. I will try to figure it out.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Put `cfdump var="passing #yourargument# to the function"` right before your function call.